# How to easily remove a large number of GPOs from Group Policy Management

Tags: group-policy

I was setting up a group policy when I noticed what appears to be a large number of GPOs created by Kasperky AV.  Im positive they were from a failed installation of the management software 2 years ago.

Unfortunately, Group Policy Management only lets you delete one GPO at a time.  I understand its a security/safety feature, so you cant accidentally delete something you shouldnt...

However, there looks to be several hundred of them and I would prefer not to delete them one at a time.  If it helps, they are all named "Kaspersky_" + a string of random letters & numbers.

Is there an easy way - perhaps a script - to delete a large number of GPOs?

Comment: You may be better served asking this question on [ServerFault](http://ServerFault.com). You can flag your question to be moved or delete this question and make a new question on that site. Please do not post on both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Open your Group Policy Management Console
- Scroll down and select `Group Policy Objects` in the left panel.  (It is displayed directly above the the WMI Filters, and Starter GPOs)
- In the right panel there will be two tabs Contents/Delegation, make sure you are on the `Contents` tab.
- Select the policies you want, using the standard Windows range selectors.  (Hold down shift to select a contiguous range, and Control to pick objects one at a time.
- Right click and delete, copy, or backup.

[image: multi select group policy]

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhhhhh.... I was trying to select them in the left panel...  Thank you, you just saved me a huge headache

Comment: I don't think that you have enough Windows Firewall rules.

Comment: @MDMarra Yup, we like having small discrete policies that are really easy to understand purely based on the full name.